# How can I ensure the next things is always at the start of a new line?

Tags: paragraphs

I have an environment that needs to ensure that its body always starts on a new line, but that doesn't add extra blank space when doing that.

[What I have](https://latexbase.com/d/abeada58-1aa9-418e-91ad-4ea2e1f30f8a) works well, except with a few corner cases relating to `\paragraph{...}` without any text between it and my environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{foo}{
\par
}{
}

\section{Foo}
\begin{foo}
OK
\end{foo}

\paragraph{Bar} chart.
\begin{foo}
OK
\end{foo}

\paragraph{Baz}
\begin{foo}
Bad
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

I can force that to start a new line by adding a `~\\` in the right spot, but that also adds a blank at the start of all the other uses that were correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an issue somewhere to provide a better interface, but you can detect a pending run-in head or list item and flush it out with `\leavevmode`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{foo}{%
\if@inlabel\leavevmode \fi
\if@noskipsec\leavevmode \fi
\par
}{
}
\makeatother
\section{Foo}
\begin{foo}
OK
\end{foo}

\paragraph{Bar} chart.
\begin{foo}
OK
\end{foo}

\paragraph{Baz}
\begin{foo}
Bad
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe it requires detailed explanation. It seems somewhat in-logical to set `\leavevmode` in order to be the next text in a new paragraph. If TeX is in vertical mode already then next text begins a new paragraph and nothing more is needed (and `\par` suggested by OP does nothing). If TeX is in horizontal mode then `\leavevmode` is irrelevant. `\par` should be sufficient. Why it doesn't in this case of LaTeX macro `\paragraph` is very interesting question.

Comment: @wipet TeX is in vmode but the run-in heading is in a box ready to be inserted by \everypar. so \par does nothing but you need to start a paragraph to fire \everypar, then the \par can end the paragraph after the inserted head.

Comment: I knew that LaTeX was unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @wipet I knew you would say that:-)

Comment: That seems to work. Regarding unnecessary complexity; the fact I'm far from sure that accounts for every place I might use that environment, and have no idea how I'd get that list places, or how I'd have things tell me if I bump into one, or how I'd figure out the correct test if I found another corner case... I kinda like TeX being so stable, but I wish it had chose a later era of language design to freeze in.

Comment: @BCS basically those two cases are the only ones needed. You don't like the 80's ? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle According to the 'pidia TeX started life more like in the 70's, and didn't even try to be Turing complete until ~5y later. At a guess its architecture wouldn't have even been close to groundbreaking even in the late 60's. Not that latest-and-greatest should be a goal, but it sometimes feels more like ASM (with a pre-processor) than a basic programming language.

Comment: @BCS sure but wipet was complaining about latex specifically,which is a child of  the 80s, and tex 78 isn't really recognisable as what is now tex, which really started with tex82